# How to make that if includeChildren is false to be able to check each single individual toggle of the include1 array of toggles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is in the loop when i set the includeChildren bool to false again i can't then select individual toggles from the include1 array because includeChildren set the include1[i] to false all the time.

```
if(includeChildren)
{
    include1[i] = true;
}
else
{
    include1[i] = false;
}
    
include1[i] = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", include1[i], GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
```

The full script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class RenameSelected : EditorWindow
{
    private static readonly Vector2Int size = new Vector2Int(500, 500);
    private string childrenPrefix;
    private int startIndex;
    private bool showPosition = false;
    private bool includeChildren = false;
    private bool[] include1;
    private bool a = false;
    private GameObject[] objects;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Rename Selected")]
    public static void Init()
    {
        EditorWindow window = GetWindow<RenameSelected>();
        window.minSize = size;
        window.maxSize = size;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        objects = Selection.gameObjects;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        objects = Selection.gameObjects;
        include1 = new bool[objects.Length];
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(10);
        childrenPrefix = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Rename prefix", childrenPrefix);
        startIndex = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Start index", startIndex);
        includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);

        if (objects.Length == 0)
        {
            showPosition = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(true, 16f, EditorStyles.foldout);
        Rect foldRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp && foldRect.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
        {
            showPosition = !showPosition;
            GUI.changed = true;
            Event.current.Use();
        }

        showPosition = EditorGUI.Foldout(foldRect, showPosition, "Objects");
        GUILayout.Space(2);

        if (showPosition)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

            scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 50;

                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(300.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
                    objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true, options);
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 112;
                    
                    if(includeChildren)
                    {
                        include1[i] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        include1[i] = false;
                    }

                    include1[i] = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", include1[i], GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Rename Objects"))
        {
            
        }

        Repaint();
    }
}
```

Some screenshot of what i'm trying to archive :

The main goal is to be able to rename multiple selection of gameobjects.

[image: Selections]

About the toggles :

I want to make that if the global variable includeChildren is true then try to get all children of all selected gameobjects in the array objects : check all the toggles of all the objects and try to get all the children of each gameobject if there is children then build a foldout tree for each gameobject so i can see all the children.

If the global variable includechildren is not checked is false the i want to be able to check set false/true each individual gameobject by checking/unchecking the toggle checkbox near it.

Comment: The code looks weird. What behavior do you want to get as a result?

Comment: @Morion the behavior i want to get as result is : list/array of selection gameobjects and each selected gameopbject to have a checkbox(toggle) near it so i can decide if to loop over this toggle for children when i selected for example 5 gameobjects in the hierarchy then i want to decide with a checkbox if to loop over children for each individual gameobject and if i do it will build a tree for that gameobject with all children if there are children.  and another global bool is to decide if to loop over children for all toggles.

Comment: @Morion the global one is the variable includeChildren and the individual is the array include1. i will add some screenshot to my question to explain.

Comment: @Morion before getting to the rename part i want first to fix and make the toggles part.  and then to add the rename part depending on the toggles behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is in your `if` part. What are you doing right now - you are syncing (`OnGUI` is called several times per frame) every bool array element with the "global" value many times per second. That's why you cannot change any of the elements individually.

What you need to do:

- in your `OnGUI` method always operate only the current value of your bool array elements
- handle the moment when your "global" value **was changed** and modify the whole bool array

I will add code partially. I think it will be enough:

```
...
void OnGUI()
{
    ...
    bool newIncludeChildrenGlobal = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);
    if (newIncludeChildrenGlobal != includeChildren)
    {
        ProcessGlobalToggleChanged(newIncludeChildrenGlobal);
    }
    includeChildren = newIncludeChildrenGlobal;

    ...

// completely remove commented code part
//
// if(includeChildren)
// {
//     include1[i] = true;
// }
// else
// {
//     include1[i] = false;
// }
    ...
}

void ProcessGlobalToggleChanged(bool newValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < include1.Length; i++)
    {
        include1[i] = newValue;
    }
}
```

If I understood what you want correctly, it should do the trick.